# Regex in java to extract string between double quotes

Tags: java, regex

Hi im able to read data between double quotes , but i stuck on this problem

> "13. The ""strange situation"" in child development is used to assess the infant's:
>   (A) level of 
>   curiosity.
>   (B) security of attachment.
>   (C) ability to relate to strangers.
>   (D) response to new types of 
>   stimulation.
>   (E) developmental status with object constancy."

I have to read data between double quotes ,but the problem is when the question itself has double quotes. How can i read the double double quotes within the double quotes ??

Is there any Regex for this

Comment: It would have been better if the question and answers were separated by a carriage return of defined in a non-ambiguous format. How would you handle `A. Same as in B. but with [...] B. Anxiety`? Also which regex have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Hi , i tried this   `( "\\d+(\\.)\\w+[?:]")` And also it does not contain options of this form  `A. Same as in B. but with [...] B. Anxiety `

Comment: Is the input text exactly as shown? There is not even a space before options `A,B,C,D` etc.

Comment: Off topic but with a little effort you could use [Sentence Boundaries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/sentence.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(.*)A\.(.*)B\.(.*)C\.(.*)D\.(.*)E\.(.*)
```

but be sure that your text contains only one :
A. B. C. D. and E.

otherwise you cannot solve this

Comment: it is returning the original text as it  is ... the regex is not working

Comment: in java you should use \ as \\

Comment: yea i used  '  \\ '  only